# how to fix the function longest_match?

Tags: python

```
def longest_match(top : str, bottom : str) -> (int,int):
    def max_same(top_start : int) -> int:
        count = 1
        i = 1
        for x in top[top_start+1:]:
            if i == len(bottom)-1:
                break
            else:
                if x == bottom[i]:
                    count += 1
                    i += 1
                else:
                    return count 
        return count

    if bottom[0] not in top:
        return (0,0)

    for i in top:
        if i == bottom[0]:
            h = top.index(i)
            break 
    return (h, max_same(h))
```

the longest_match function, which takes two arguments: a top and bottom string representing DNA strands; it returns a 2-tuple of the starting index in the top strand that matches the longest sequence of characters starting at the beginning of the bottom strand, and the number of matching characters. For example, longest_match ('accgt,'ccg’) returns (1,3); longest_match ('accgt,'ca’) returns (1,1)

max_same function local to longest_match that takes a starting index (for the top strand) and computes and returns how many consecutive characters starting at the beginning of the bottom strand match it.

my function works for the following three cases:

```
longest_match('accgt','at')-->(0, 1)
longest_match('accgt','ccgt')-->(1, 4)
longest_match('accgt','x')-->(0, 0)
```

but for the following two cases:

```
longest_match('accgt','a')-->(0, 1)
longest_match('accgt','ccg')-->(1, 3)
```

it raises the following error:

```
*Error: longest_match('accgt','a') raised exception IndexError: string index out of range
*Error: longest_match('accgt','ccg') raised exception IndexError: string index out of range
```

can someone help me to fix my function?

Comment: Which lines of code raise the exceptions? I suggest using an IDE with a debugger, such as PyCharm. You can set a breakpoint at the line which causes the exception and inspect the values of variables. You can also step through your code to see what it is doing and figure out why it behaves differently than you expect.

Comment: if x == bottom[i]:

Comment: You are walking off the end of the list. You need a condition to check if `i` becomes too large.

Comment: Are you doing problems from rosalind.info?

Comment: I added an if statement that:  if i == len(bottom)-1:
                break  But it still gives me the same error

Comment: Then you did not add the `if` in the correct place. Or maybe you need to do something different than just `break`.

Comment: Rather fixing the problem by trial and error, you should use a debugger to find out what you are actually doing wrong.